# Docker Cloud Disable service endpoints

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-cloud

I might not fully understand this but I shall try and explain. My aim is to disable the urls that are generated for services and container endpoints in docker cloud.

[image]

It is my understanding that unless you publish the port only other local containers on the host can access that port. However Docker Cloud creates a service endpoint url for every port exposed by the docker containers as defined in their dockerfile. I do not like the idea that some of my containers which i expect to be accessible only locally are exposed publicly via Docker Clouds url.

I understand that the service urls are generated, however they are still accessible publicly. 
Can I disable the automatic generation of service endpoints, or have them locked down behind authentication hence only I can log in, (I would prefer the former).

Any clarity on this subject would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The Publishing of the ports was recently enhanced and now it's up to you if the ports are published to the internet.